# Why does my horizontal bar chart stacked not show certain values in different colors?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am using Excel 2016 from Office 365 on Windows 10 and I can't get my horizontal bar chart (stacked) to show my 3 sets of values on each stacked bar. Can anyone help?

This is supposed to be a chart like a Gantt chart to show the progress of a progress over several months time.

I have two categories which should represent Cities and 3 sets of values - each set has a start dates and then days representing how long the project took--the actual time, the scheduled time and any holidays in between.

My data is arranged like this:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuAiT.png)

My chart looks like this and I don't understand (the 'I need to delete' comment just means that I need to make that color clear b/c the actual work schedule starts on 4/23/2016 for City bc (it will look like a Gantt chart):
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnhvA.png)

Where are the 3 colors that should be in each bar? It should have 3 colors for City c - a bar starting from 3/29/2016 extending 10 days for actual days of project, another bar within the 1st bar from 3/29 only extending 5 days for scheduled days "", and yet another bar within the 1st bar from 4/1/2016 extending 15 days for the holidays.

Same for the City bc - a bar from 4/23 for 15 days for actual, a bar within that from 4/23 for 25 days for scheduled, and a bar within that again from 5/1/2016 for 5 days for holidays.

Here are my settings under 'Design' (when chart selected)>'Select Data' in Excel (I can't post a 3rd picture per the forum but the settings are...):
1)The whole chart is selected under **Chart Data Range**.
2)**Legend Entries (Series)**:
Added start as label name - and values in column B under start (3/29/2016 and 4/23/2016 selected)
Added a 2nd entry - day as label name  - and values in column B under day (10 and 15 selected)
Added a 3rd entry - start sched as label name - and values in column D under start sched (3/29/2016 and 4/23/2016 from column D)
Added a 4th entry for day sched
Added a 5th entry for start hol
Added a 6th and final entry for day hol

3) For **Horizontal (Category) axis labels**:
Added values in column A under Cities (c and bc)

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I tried looking via Goggle and help menu - can you upload files to Super User (my 2nd time to a Stackoverflow/Super User forum)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Gantt chart, although not a standard Excel chart type, can be simulated with a Stacked Bar chart and a simple trick. There are two questions about how to format the data and the chart.

### Where are the three colors on the chart?

First let's consider city c. The orange bar comes from the `day` cell in the data, it starts at 3/29/2016, and it's 10 days long. However, the gray bar is a problem. It comes from the `start sched` cell, and it starts at 4/8/2016. But, remember that Excel dates are day numbers, therefore the gray bar for 3/29/2016 is 42,458 days long, which means it ends on 7/7/2132! If you could scroll across to 7/7/2132, the `day sched` cell is there and it's 5 days long.

[image: data and bar chart for city c]

City bc has the same problem with the gray bar for 4/23/2016, which is 42,483 days long.

[image: data and bar chart for city bc]

These dates in the `start sched` column are the reason the bars don't display three colors.

### How can Excel simulate a Gantt chart?

The dates in the `Start` cells are the beginning of the tasks for cites c and bc. We don't want to actually delete your blue bar for city bc, because the `Start` cell is the date that the task begins. Of course, city c also has a blue bar, but it's off the chart to the left.

Instead, the trick to simulating a Gantt chart is to format the first data series (Start) with no fill, which makes the color clear. Change the horizontal axis bounds to start at the serial day number of the earliest start date (3/29/2016 in the example), and end after the latest of the start dates plus total durations (4/29/2016 plus 20 days).

[image: Start series with no fill]

### Arranging the data

The reason that Excel dates in the data are a problem is because the large numbers create long bars which make the chart useless. To make a chart you can use, rearrange the data to move the dates to other cells if you need them.

For a Gantt-like chart, the row for each city needs a start date with additional columns of durations in days. The values for the duration series are days from the start date, but formulas can be used to compute days as the percent completion of a task, or days allocated to portions of a task. Here's a example that shows how to arrange data for a Gantt-like chart in cell `A1`. The duration numbers are chosen to display bars with different lengths.

```
City    Start   Duration 1  Duration 2  Duration 3
c   3/29/2016   10          15          5
bc  4/23/2016   15          5           0
```

The Stacked Bar chart for this sample data has four data series: Start, Duration 1, Duration 2, and Duration 3.

[image: Stacked Bar chart data series]

```
Series     Name          Y values
---------- ------------  -----------------
Start      =Sheet1!$B$1  =Sheet1!$B$2:$B$3
Duration 1 =Sheet1!$C$1  =Sheet1!$C$2:$C$3
Duration 2 =Sheet1!$D$1  =Sheet1!$D$2:$D$3
Duration 3 =Sheet1!$E$1  =Sheet1!$E$2:$E$3
```

Again, it's important to format the `Start` series for no fill.

### A Gantt-like chart example

Here's how to make a simple Gantt-like chart that uses the above data layout and bar chart. The method uses `IF` formulas to fill in the duration cells for city c.

Use cell `C5` for the number of days scheduled for a task, and cell `C6` for the actual number of days.

Enter these formulas in cells `C2` to `E2`:

```
C2:  =IF(C6>C5,C5,C6)
D2:  =IF(C6<=C5,C5-C6,0)
E2:  =IF(C6>C5,C6-C5,0)
```

I've recolored the series for Duration 1, 2 and 3 to yellow, green and red respectively.

The formula in `C2` shows the number of actual days used as a yellow bar.
`D2` shows the number of schedule-days remaining as a green bar.
`E2` shows the number of days after the schedule is exceeded as a red bar.

For example, assume a task is scheduled to last 10 days (enter `10` in cell `C5`).

- When there no actual days (cell `C6` is zero), the chart is a green bar 10 days long. The green bar indicates that no work has started.
- If two actual days are used, the chart is a yellow bar two days long, and a green bar 8 days long, meaning there are 8 schedule-days remaining.
- After 10 actual days, the yellow bar is 10 days long, and there is no green bar. All scheduled days are used.
- If there are more than 10 actual days, the yellow bar is 10 days long, and there's a red bar showing the number of days that exceed the schedule.

Here's an animation that shows how the chart changes for 0 to 20 actual days.

[image: animation for actual days]

Comment: creidhne, thank you so much. I didn't think of arranging my data that way; however, what if my holiday start date starts at something other than 3/29/2016 like in City c? Is that where using a formula for 'days allocated to portions of a task' comes into play? Can you give an example of a formula for days allocated to portions of a task?  Thank you, again.

Comment: creidhne, please ignore that. I couldn't edit it in time, but I understand what you did. I don't understand why you added 5 and 0 for the schedule day and holiday day for City bc, though? I understand 5 is to show 25 days past start date minus the 5 day holiday, but the 5 day holiday I had from 5/1 for 5 days doesn't show up as it's own color. Is that where a formula for 'days allocated to portions of a task' comes into play? Can you give an ex: of that formula?  I tried an IF formula and I don't see how I could add numbers to show from 5/1/2016 to 5/5/2016, the holiday day for City bc.

Comment: @sturdy267 I'll change the answer and maybe that will help to explain what's happening your data and the chart... coming soon! I'm confused by your bars within bars, and the dates you mentioned don't seem to add up, but I'll add an example for how to use days allocated to the tasks, such as days scheduled, days used, and days after the allotted schedule.

Comment: @sturdy267, if this solves your problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark.  It helps other users with a similar problem by identifying proven solutions.  It also awards a little rep to the author and you for the effort.

Comment: @creidhne, thank you so much for your reply. I've tried both solutions out and it helps, but, if you don't mind, I need a horiz stacked bar chart w/ actual days, scheduled days, and holidays all in 3 different colors on the each stacked bar for City c and bc. I charted your data set with the 3 durations above and it works but, for ex:, the 5 day holiday I had for bc from 5/1 for 5 days in my original ex: doesn't show up as it's own color. I realize I can't use the dates now, but the 5 day holiday should show up as another color within the bar for actual days. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @fixer1234 yes, it's still pending, but I will follow through. Thank you for the heads up. I appreciate this site! I just learned to vote and voted for credihne.

Comment: @sturdy267, Super User's purpose is a knowledge base of bite-sized problems and solutions.  The intended scope is something that can be answered in a few paragraphs.  Developing a custom application or providing general training on a subject is generally outside of that scope.  I posted my earlier comment because I was so impressed with how far above and beyond creidhne had gone with this answer.  In fairness, if it isn't quite what you're looking for and you can't figure out how to adapt it, consider asking a new follow-up question that asks how to take it the next step.

Comment: @sturdy267, fixer1234 makes a good point. How about we call this question about why there aren't 3 colors and how to remove the first bar for a Gantt chart as answered. Your data and chart for this question don't help to show what you wanted to do, but the good news is that we have data arrangement and a chart that you can work with. That much is fixed. Try using the new data and chart to work on a solution.

Comment: @sturdy267, I don't understand how the bars within bars are supposed to work . Where does each bar start and end? What happens if there are no actual days? What happens if the actual days exceed the schedule? Where does the holiday fit in? Try changing the `IF` formulas in my example. Add more Duration columns if you need them. If you can't find formulas that work, then type numbers into the Duration cells to make a new chart that shows how you want the bars to look even if there are no formulas. Try different actual, schedule and holidays. Use what you come up with to ask a new question.

Comment: @creidhne, yes, I thought I was being descriptive by using examples, but I will consider a follow up question another time if further trials don't help. The question is unanswered but I will select answered in that you helped me very much by redirecting me in the right direction re: rearranging the data and the use of formulas. If I can reward you further, besides upvoting which I did yesterday, then let me know.